USB cables being affected by manufacturing equipment
I am an IT guy, who enjoys learning about some of the electrical engineering side of things, but I don't have a good grasp of the jargon.
We have a client with about 40 different smaller production lines - actually packaging lines. We have recently placed PCs at each line and about 5 of the PCs have interference with the USB keyboards attached to them. When the lines are actually turned on, then the computers will magically start typing random characters on the screen. Some of the lines are larger than other lines, but I don't know exactly how much power they are using - 240, 480, etc. We tried some Ferrite Beads on the USB cables, but that did not help. From what I am reading here, I might should have tried many different sizes. The monitors are touch screens, and the connections to the computer for keyboard and "mouse" are still connected to the computer via USB and the interference continues.
The computers are connected to the same power circuit as the machines in most cases. The maintenance guys have broken out their power to 110 outlets for the computers and other miscellaneous equipment.
What would be the best way to address the interference? Would I expect it to be coming from a bad ground in the equipment? Any way to address it in the USB cables themselves?

It is somewhat common in cheap USB1 devices to use ordinary, non-twisted, non-controlled impedance wires for data cables.  My first thought would be that you have such a marginal cable and should try another keyboard, especially one that uses USB2 speeds (e.g. has a USB2 hub in it).  This might (never tried it!) be better since that will force much better attention to signal integrity.

Unfortunately USB  doesn’t seem to be too robust in an industrial setting and what you’re experiencing is not unusual. You need to consider how the computer and monitor are mounted and the routing of the cables. Your touch screen might need to be electrically isolated from any metal frame. If there are variable speed drives in the vicinity, then these must have the correct shielded cabling to the motors otherwise they cause extreme interference.

The problem isn't disturbance affecting USB, but the disturbance affecting the keyboard which detects the disturbance accidentally as valid key presses and then tve key presses are prefectly sent without problems through USB.
USB is a pretty robust protocol with error checking and handshaking if transmitted packets are OK and received without errors so it is extremely unlikely that the problem is in the USB itself. Any disturbance affecting the USB would cause it to simply not work and keep disconnecting and reconnecting the keyboard instead of messages turning into incorrect keypresses.
Test by wrapping the keyboard in tin foil. Maybe tie the tinfoil to mains PE for better shielding effect. If it prevents the disturbances then it was the keyboard, buy better ones.

In an industrial setting, I would be HIGHLY SUSPECT of any PE connection in the facility, as far as EMI is concerned. Ground it to the PC.

@TimWilliams The PC would also be grounded to mains PE, so same difference. Fair enough, maybe I should have said to connect it to mains PE through the PC case.

If the issue is EMI, a lead length (from the shield to reference plane) of some inches might be enough to obviate it; and some meters, enough to make things considerably worse. PE is a galvanic connection only; the EMI sources near any given connection induce, in general, uncorrelated noise between those points. Likewise, the PC's power cord passes through unknown fields, very likely uncorrelated to points elsewhere in the facility.  Without a ground reference for the keyboard itself (metal enclosure / ground plane), the next best one is the PC it's plugged into.

(Note that even this is an oversimplification, as it's not even the points, but the paths between them that matter. This is ultimately an EM field problem. The best case is to ground the foil to the PC, and wrap the cable with foil as well.)

I agree with Justme. To get a character from a wired USB keyboard, the keyboard has to respond to interrupt token with a data packet with make-break codes, and if it is garbage/badCRC, the host won't ACK and no characters would go out of the keyboard driver to system. Most USB keyboards use capacitive touch pads, so there must be a significant EMI to generate false touch events. This environment likely needs some industrial-grade keyboards.
